# using DateFormat to produce a "2016-12-28T17:43:47.345Z"

Tags: date, datetime, datepicker, format, dart

I have been looking at the above question and have most of it correct.

I am going to get a datetime in Zulu, and then will want to output that format.

My first go is just as simple as:

```
DateFormat format = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

My issue I am having is the `T` and `Z`.  Obviously T is used to separate the date from the time and the Z is representative of Zulu time.

That being said the users will be entering a datetime in Zulu, so it wont need to be converted from Local to Zulu, so i was not sure if `'Z'` is an acceptable result.  I was not sure if there is a different want to handle this, or if my result was the best answer.

Comment: So you really just want to convert a DateTime to a ISO 8601 formatted String representation??? Is there a reason why DateTime.toIso8601String() does not do what you want?

Comment: i was unfamiliar with that term *ISO 8601*.  If that is the format, I will use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime object has a method called: `toIso8601String` which is used to return an ISO formatted string.  The 'Z' will be added if isUTC is true, otherwise the result will not have the Z in it.

Make sure that the DateTime object itself is correctly set to UTC as if you look in the constructor for the class will tell you a lot of the defaults are local with the exception of the DateTime.utc() static function.

In that concept, you dont really need a DateFormat use to define an iso string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy).

```
String isoFomart = Jiffy.now().format(); // This will return ISO format from now
```

You can also add your DateTime object

```
String isoFomart = Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime.now()).format(); // This will also return ISO format from now
```

Hope this helped